# My SQL query to fetch results from database is not working

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to fetch all columns from the `Users` table, to store in `holder` as an array so that I can access all the rows from it. But the problem is when I put a breakpoint in the code, the `holder` variable only shows the value `Webmatrix.Data.Database`, why is that?

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("test");
    var holder = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = 1");
}
```

It's obviously wrong, so please correct my mistakes :) Thanks!

(*edited to include the second double-quote that was in my actual code, but missed out in this question*)

Comment: First mistake, you're missing a second double-quote `"` to end the SQL string. Also, this seems like something that would be incredibly trivial for you to Google and resolve for yourself - have you tried doing so already, or did you just come straight here?

Comment: That was an error on my part when creating the question, the second double-quote is in my actual code but it does return the value that I wrote in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is missing the closing double-quotes (`"`). The following will work:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("test");
    var holder = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = 1");
}
```